# Docker expose port - OCI runtime create failed

Tags: node.js, express, docker, dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:9.4
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app
CMD node app.js
EXPOSE 80
```

**Node / Express code**

```
var socket_number = 80
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
....
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
http.listen(socket_number);
```

**Run**

```
C:\Users\john_\Documents\GitHub\purple_cloud>docker run 171b2830a121 -p 3000:80
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused “exec: “-p”: executable file not found in $PATH”: unknown.
```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

**Observation**

`docker run 171b2830a121` without the "`-p 3000:80`" does not generate the error, but can't access port 80 or 3000.

> node app.js ... works correctly

Comment: expose before cmd ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-arrange your arguments to `docker run`. Assuming your image name is `171b2830a121` then it should be:

```
docker run -p 3000:80 171b2830a121
```